# Expected sum of Poisson Process

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let a probability process follows the Poisson distribution with parameter ($\lambda$). Now each time an event has occurred, I will be paid $K \$$. What is the expected sum I will receive?

Actually, I am confused about probability mass function in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

The $\textit{pmf}$ of the poisson distribution talks about probability of occurrance of $n$ events. But I know, in order to calculate the expected sum, I need to calculate: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k p(k)$. Where, $p(k)$ is the probability of occurrance of $k^{th}$ event.

Should I calculate conditional probability of each event, and thereby calculate the infinite sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you must find the expected amount of money that you will have received at moment $t$.

Let $N_t$ denote the number of events that occurred during time span $[0,t]$.

Then $N_t\sim\mathsf{Poisson}(\lambda t)$ so that $\mathbb EN_t=\lambda t$, and at moment $t$ you have receive $KN_t$ dollars.

We find the expectation as follows: $$\mathbb EKN_t=K\mathbb EN_t=K\lambda t$$

---

**edit**:

If you receive $k$ dollars at the $k$-th event then the amount of money received at moment $t$ is $$1+2+\cdots+N_t=\frac12N_t(N_t+1)$$

Can you find the expectation of this yourself?

Comment: I suspect that you have assumed the occurrence of t independent Poisson process, and that's why you could add up the independent Poisson process. Isn't it?

Comment: I was thinking about a [homegeneous Poisson point process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Interpreted_as_a_point_process_on_the_real_line).

Comment: $K$ is not constant. You are absolutely right that I am interested in events occurred during time span $[0,t]$. The occurrence of events are defined by, $\lambda$ events per time interval $[0,t]$. I am counting the events. Each time an event occurs I get some money. If $k^{th}$ event occurs, I get $k$ $\$$. Will the result still be same?

Comment: This makes things different and it needs a second look. Btw, you say $\lambda$ events per time interval $[0,t]$. Don't you mean $\lambda$ events per time interval $[0,1]$, hence $\lambda t$ events per time interval $[0,t]$?

Comment: No. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: I have edited. Knowing that a random variable $X$ has Poisson distribution you must find $\mathbb EX(X+1)$.

Comment: Ok. This seems reasonable to me. If $N_t$ event occurs within a time period, then, I can calculate the sum I receive using the $n^{th}$ sum of natural numbers, I already know the $pmf$, Then I can easily calculate the expected sum. However, I was more interested in the individual process. Given that the first event has occurred, can I calculate the probability of $2^{nd}$ process by conditional probability?

Comment: I guess so, but it goes too far to discuss this here. I think it is better to ask a new question about that, eventually equipped with a link to this question.

Comment: New question is added in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2782060/combination-of-two-independent-poisson-process